# Load time of Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, page-load-time

I'm currently working on Laravel 4 and bootstrap.css. I'm currently designing/implementing the front-end/back-end features, and couldn't help, but notice, that the performance of serving my resources is really slow.

```
My system config is:
- am developing on localhost.
- have set the database host to 127.0.0.1 (in case it does matter)
- Ubuntu, Mysql, php
```

and found out that it's not the db which is the one responsible for the performance issue. Most responses are served between 700 and 800ms. But the page render takes around more then 5 seconds which is insanely slow (yet again: I'm on local). This problem is persistence in production environment too.

Comment: I am using apache server. The issue is that the page gets the view but the completes rendering after sometime.

Answer (score 4):

Simply Use this code

```
This page took {{ (microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START) }} seconds to render
```

Output Likes :

```
This page took 0.1246546165498 seconds to render
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you use `php artisan serve` or apache/nginx? The built in PHP webserver does not cache anything, so it'll have to reload everything on every request. Additionally, you might want to try something that minimizes your CSS/Javascript, like [Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline), or [Laravel Guard](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Guard).

You could also install the [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), which shows you which queries are fired, how long a request took, the memory usage, and more. Using the debugbar slows down pageload a bit, but it does give you more insight into why your pages are slow.

Comment: another really great and powerful tool is Clockwork (https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) which profiles your laravel and makes it viewable within chrome dev tools (requests, sql queries, used routes, ...). maybe this points you into the right direction.